# Accessing Spring MessageSource from Struts tags

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, struts2, textfield

I'm using Spring 3 for IOC and Struts 2 for MVC (so I'm using Struts Actions for all the work, and Struts tags in my JSPs).

I'd like to internationalize the application. I'm using Spring MessageSource that reads it's content from a JDBC message provider.

All my Actions are ServletRequestAware which I use to get the ApplicationContext and get the Spring beans. So, I have also my MessageSource-bean available. (And of course a ResourceBundle from MessageSourceResourceBundle).

What I would like to be able to do is use the ResourceBundle in my struts-tags.
The example for `<s:textfield>` says:

> In this example, a text control for the "user" property is rendered. The label is also >retrieved from a ResourceBundle via the key attribute.
>   `<s:textfield key="user">`

Not Sure what that means. In my mind, you need a "bundle" and a "key" to get a message from a bundle. So what is "user" in the example above, a "bundle" or a "key"? 
How should I forward my ResourceBundle to the jsp, via Action's getter or through request parameter?

Comment: `<s:textfield key="user">` this means that Set the key (name, value, label) for this particular component